# Do I need to recheck my baggage when transiting in AMS

Tags: air-travel, international-travel, bookings, airport-transfer, airport-security

I am travelling from USA to INDIA through AMS, do I need to check in my luggage at AMS again?
It was a single reservation, I got my whole ticket together.

Answer (score 3):

No, if both your flights are on the same ticket, you don't need to collect or recheck your luggage in AMS.

Your luggage will be "checked-through" at your airport or departure, and you won't see it in AMS. As you are doing a non-Schengen to non-Schengen transit, you will stay airside (in the "international area" of the airport), and won't need to go through passport control.

If you have Indian citizenship, you don't need a visa, and don't need an airport transit visa (ATV) either.

Comment: Thank youuuuu:)